# MySQL Select data from table with dates between in reverse of interval 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL requirement to select data from a table based on a start date and end date and group it by weekly also selecting the data in reverse order by date. Assume that, I have chosen the start date as ***`1st November and the end date as 04 December.`*** Now, I would like to fetch the data as **`04 December to 28 November, 27 November to 20 November, 19 November to 12 November`** and so on and sum the value count for that week.

Given an example table,

| id | value | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2021-10-11 |
| 2 | 13 | 2021-10-17 |
| 3 | 11 | 2021-10-25 |
| 4 | 8 | 2021-11-01 |
| 5 | 1 | 2021-11-10 |
| 6 | 4 | 2021-11-18 |
| 7 | 34 | 2021-11-25 |
| 8 | 17 | 2021-12-04 |

Now the result should be like 2021-12-04 to 2021-11-28 as one week, following the same in reverse order and summing the column value data for that week. I have tried in the query to add the interval of 7 days after the end date but it didn't work.

```
SELECT count(value) AS total, MIN(R.created_at) 
FROM data_table AS D 
WHERE D.created_at BETWEEN '2021-11-01' AND '2021-12-04'  - INTERVAL 7 DAY  ORDER BY D.created_at;
```

And it's also possible to have the last week may have lesser than 7 days.

Expected output:

| end_interval | start_interval | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-04 | 2021-11-27 | 17 |
| 2021-11-27 | 2021-11-20 | 34 |
| 2021-11-20 | 2021-11-13 | 4 |
| 2021-11-13 | 2021-11-06 | 1 |
| 2021-11-06 | 2021-10-30 | 8 |
| 2021-10-30 | 2021-10-25 | 11 |

Note that the last week is only 5 days depending upon the selected from and end dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to address this problem is to

- generate a calendar of all your intervals, beginning from last date till first date, with a split of your choice, using a recursive query
- joining back the calendar with the original table
- capping start_interval at your start_date value
- aggregating values for each interval

You can have three variables to be set, to customize your date intervals and position:

```
SET @start_date = DATE('2021-10-25');
SET @end_date = DATE('2021-12-04');
SET @interval_days = 7;
```

Then use the following query, as already described:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT @end_date AS end_interval,
           DATE_SUB(@end_date, INTERVAL @interval_days DAY) AS start_interval
    UNION ALL
    SELECT start_interval AS end_interval, 
           GREATEST(DATE(@start_date), DATE_SUB(start_interval, INTERVAL @interval_days DAY)) AS start_interval
    FROM cte
    WHERE start_interval > @start_date
)
SELECT end_interval, start_interval, SUM(_value) AS total
FROM      cte
LEFT JOIN tab
       ON tab.created_at BETWEEN start_interval AND end_interval
GROUP BY end_interval, start_interval
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/guRLYSH7gudiEiG1JnbA6i/2).

Comment: I really appreciate your time for answering the question. It almost helped me to solve the issue. Although, in the query, the result is showing till 2021-10-16 however, the end date is 2021-10-25. Is there any way we can control the last week even if it's lesser than 7 days?

Comment: Can you share the expected output in your post? I have an idea about it, but I want to make sure what I think is actually what you need.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question with the expected answer.

Comment: A couple of fixes: one on the recursive condition `WHERE start_interval > @start_date`, and the addition of `GREATEST(@start_date, DATE_SUB(...))` to make all the interval consistent with the range [@start_date, @end_date]

Comment: I've tried updating the query with the above. Bit confused on the GREATEST() in the sql

Comment: It returns the bigger date. Among 10-25 and 11-06? 11-06. Among 10-25 and 10-30? 10-30. Among 10-25 and 10-23? 10-25. Among 10-25 and any date the goes below 10-25? Always capping at 10-25.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250404/discussion-between-musthafa-and-lemon).